# Cannot format given Object as a Number ComboBox

Tags: java, combobox

How can I set an integer number into double? Let's say I have a comboBox named day, and it has 1,2,,3 elements. I want to set it as two decimal point. If user select 1, it will become 1.00. How can I do that?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        String a=(String)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                        //Integer b=(comboBox_1.getSelectedIndex()+1);
                        int day=(Integer)comboBox_2.getSelectedItem();
                        double bo;
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");      
                        bo= Double.valueOf(df.format(day));
```

Error I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:507)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
    at gui.User.<init>(User.java:105)
    at gui.User$1.run(User.java:49)
```

Comment: There's not enough code to reproduce your problem. `DecimalFormat.format(long)` (which you are calling in your code snippet) should work for all values of int. Are you sure the exception is from this line?

Comment: Use `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");` and then `df.format(day)`, No need for double conversion

Comment: int i = 3; 
double d = (double) i;

Comment: is it possible to format an int comboBox to two decimal places like the way I did?

Comment: @anirudh How about comboBox?    int day=(Integer)comboBox_2.getSelectedItem();

Comment: use integer .ParseInt

Comment: int day= Integer.parseInt(comboBox_2.getSelectedItem());

Comment: sorry, I new to java, can't get it..can you explain more ? Thanks :)

Comment: @Vaulstein it asks me change type of 'bo' to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    String a=comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    //Integer b=(comboBox_1.getSelectedIndex()+1);
                    int day=Integer.ParseInt(comboBox_2.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    double bo;
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");      
                    bo=  Double.parseDouble(df.format(day));
```

Comment: the bo cannot be double type...and I want it be double

Comment: ya..change type of bo to String..cannot convert from string to double

Comment: where is the string which is converting to double ?

Comment: the method doubleValue() is undefined for type string

Comment: ok then this will help u..  Double.parseDouble(df.format(day));