# Formatting using DecimalFormat throws exception - "Cannot format given Object as a Number"

Tags: java, exception, overloading, illegalargumentexception, decimalformat

This might look like a repeated question but I tried in all the below links and can't get a proper answer.

[Cannot format given Object as a Number ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174400/cannot-format-given-object-as-a-number-combobox)

[Illegal Argument Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780237/illegal-argument-exception)

But I'm not getting what's wrong. Here is my code

```
DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double externalmark = 1.86;
double internalmark = 4.0;
System.out.println(String.valueOf((externalmark*3+internalmark*1)/4));
String val = String.valueOf((externalmark*3+internalmark*1)/4);
String wgpa1=twoDForm.format(val); // gives exception
String wgpa2=twoDForm.format((externalmark*3+internalmark*1)/4)); // works fine
System.out.println(wgpa1);
```

The `format` method takes Object type argument, so that's why I passed a String object which gives exception

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot**
>   **format given Object as a Number.**

But when I give double value as argument the program works fine. But if the method is defined with `Object` type argument why I'm getting an exception while passing a `String` and not getting exception while passing `double`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `format()` method of `DecimalFormat` is overloaded.

In the working case, you are invoking :

```
 public final String format(double number)
```

And in the failing case, you are invoking :

```
 public final String format (Object obj)
```

The first method takes a very  specific argument. It expects a `double`.

This is not the case of the second one, which the type accepted is very broad : `Object` and where so the check on the type passed is performed at runtime.

By providing a argument that is not a `double` but a `String`, the method invoked is the second one.

Under the hood, this method relies on the `format(Object number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos)` method that expects to a `number` argument that is an instance of the `Number` class (`Short`, `Long`, ... `Double`):

```
@Override
public final StringBuffer format(Object number,
                                 StringBuffer toAppendTo,
                                 FieldPosition pos) {
    if (number instanceof Long || 
        number instanceof Integer ||                   
        number instanceof Short || 
        number instanceof Byte ||                   
        number instanceof AtomicInteger ||
        number instanceof AtomicLong ||
        (number instanceof BigInteger && ((BigInteger)number).bitLength () < 64)) {

        return format(((Number)number).longValue(), toAppendTo, pos);
    } else if (number instanceof BigDecimal) {
        return format((BigDecimal)number, toAppendTo, pos);
    } else if (number instanceof BigInteger) {
        return format((BigInteger)number, toAppendTo, pos);
    } else if (number instanceof Number) {
        return format(((Number)number).doubleValue(), toAppendTo, pos);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot format given Object as a Number");
    }
}
```

But it is not the case as you passed to it a `String` instance.

To solve the problem, either pass a `double` primitive as in the success case or convert your `String` into an instance of `Number` such as `Double` with `Double.valueOf(yourString)`.
I advise the first way (passing a `double`) as it is more natural in your code that already uses `double` primitives.
The second one requires a additional conversion operation from `String` to `Double`.

Comment: Hello YCF ! I start to go much better ! It is great. And you how are you ? :)

Comment: With great pleasure as the last time :)

Answer (score 2):

If there is any mathematical calculation then using **java.math.BigDecimal** class's methods are the better choice for accuracy in result and efficient in performance even numbers are too large.
**Using java.math.BigDecimal code :**

```
double externalmark1 = 1.86;
double internalmark2 = 4.0;
System.out.println(String.valueOf((externalmark1*3+internalmark2*1)/4));
System.out.println("------------------------");

BigDecimal decimalValue1 = new BigDecimal((externalmark1*3+internalmark2*1)/4).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);       
System.out.println("aggregatemark [direct decimalValue]: "+decimalValue1.toString());
System.out.println("------------------------");

double aggregatemark = (externalmark1*3+internalmark2*1)/4;
System.out.println("aggregatemark [double]: "+aggregatemark);       
BigDecimal decimalValue2 = new BigDecimal(aggregatemark).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);     
System.out.println("aggregatemark [decimalValue]: "+decimalValue2.toString());
System.out.println("------------------------");

String aggregatemarkStr = String.valueOf((externalmark1*3+internalmark2*1)/4);
System.out.println("aggregatemark [string] : "+aggregatemarkStr);       
BigDecimal decimalValue3 = new BigDecimal(aggregatemarkStr).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);      
System.out.println("aggregatemark [decimalValue]: "+decimalValue3.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#format-java.lang.Object-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.text.FieldPosition-).  It says clearly, "The number can be of any subclass of Number", and it says that it throws `IllegalArgumentException` "if number is null or not an instance of Number."

(So why don't they just make the parameter a `Number` type?  Because the class is a subclass of the abstract [`Format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) class that isn't restricted to numeric formatting.  The expectation, apparently, is that while the general `Format` class has a method with an `Object` parameters, subclasses of `Format` are expected to limit the parameters to the object types that they can handle, which they have to do at run time.)