# Error when passing the input text value to DecimalFormat

Tags: java, string, decimalformat

I want pass the input text value to decimal format. To save the value as decimal format in the database. but I got an error below code. can any one explain the  error of the code.

```
DecimalFormat decimalformat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String dp = decimalformat.format(mf.getParameter("pprice"));
product.setPrice((Double.parseDouble(dp)));
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a
>   Number    at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:507)   at
>   java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)  at
>   Servlet.product.save_product.doPost(save_product.java:66)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" name="pprice"/>
```

Comment: What exactly does `mf.getParameter("pprice")` return?

Comment: it returns string value

Comment: String is not supported by the format method. It needs to be an instance of Number. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274167/formating-using-decimalformat-thows-exception-cannot-format-given-object-as-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of issues here.

1. As mentioned in the comments, you cannot provide the `DecimalFormat.format` method with a `String` value. It needs to be a subtype of `Number`. This can be solved by parsing the response of `mf.getParameter("pprice"))` to a double. Like this: 
   `decimalformat.format(Double.parseDouble(mf.getParameter("pprice")));`
2. There is really no point in doing this at all when you are converting it back to a Double afterwards. You might as well just do 
   `product.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(mf.getParameter("pprice")));`. The formatting is lost anyways.