# How to input decimals in java

Tags: java, decimalformat

I want to make sure that I understand how to change characters (mainly "." into "," and vice versa).

So I wrote a program, but I can't type in a decimal number. What should I do?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*;

public class decimalFormat {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        DecimalFormat df= new DecimalFormat("##,##0.00");
        String s= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter a number");
        s= df.format(s);
        double t=Double.parseDouble(s);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your number rounded to two digits is");
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274167/formating-using-decimalformat-throws-exception-cannot-format-given-object-as

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`DecimalFormat.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-) instead of [`DecimalFormat.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Format.html#format-java.lang.Object-). `parse()` is used to convert a `String` to a `Number`, `format()` is used to convert a `Number` to a `String`.

From the docs:

> **`parse()`**: Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a number.
>
> **`format()`**: Formats an object to produce a string.

Your code should look like this:

```
DecimalFormat df= new DecimalFormat("##,##0.00");
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter a number");
double t = df.parse(s).doubleValue();
```